# Formatting text in a LibreOffice Calc cell

Tags: images, libreoffice-calc

Currently I'm working on the layout of a calendar for the new year 2013. I found a template that was designed in LibreOffice Calc.

How can I layout the text in the cell of a Calc program? What can I do so the text looks better and is well formatted?

See [this document](http://www.schulcenter.org/image_uploads/Losungen_Free_2013_Transponiert.ods).

I'd like to have something like this in the end:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first image link wasn't working. Please upload images using our own uploader and embed them here, on-site, like I did with the two other images. Also, please respect proper capitalization in English (e.g., i → I). Almost all of your posts needed to be edited in some way.